# PHP - Display 2 dimension array with foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to display a 2 dimension array. I tried to use a double foreach  to make it but im a bit lost. It return's me an empty td and i dont know why. Im using ZendFramework. Should i use an other solution and leave the foreach solution or i just miss something ?

The array ( there is 7 arrays inside one array and the columns are always the same ) :

```
array(7) {
[0]=>
array(11) {
["'01.drplapostej-1'"]=>
string(20) "01. DRP La poste J-1"
["import"]=>
string(1) "0"
["radm_ok"]=>
string(1) "0"
["radm_rejet"]=>
string(1) "0"
["radm_ko"]=>
string(1) "0"
["rpec_ok"]=>
string(1) "0"
["rpec_rejet"]=>
string(1) "0"
["rpec_ko"]=>
string(1) "0"
["factu_ok"]=>
string(1) "0"
["factu_rejet"]=>
string(1) "0"
["factu_ko"]=>
string(1) "0"
}
[1]=>
array(11) {
["'01.drplapostej-1'"]=>
string(20) "02. DRL La poste J-1"
["import"]=>
string(2) "80"
["radm_ok"]=>
string(1) "0"
["radm_rejet"]=>
string(1) "0"
["radm_ko"]=>
string(1) "0"
["rpec_ok"]=>
string(1) "0"
["rpec_rejet"]=>
string(1) "0"
["rpec_ko"]=>
string(1) "0"
["factu_ok"]=>
string(1) "0"
["factu_rejet"]=>
string(1) "0"
["factu_ko"]=>
string(1) "0"
}
```

What i tried to do :

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>01.DRPLAPOSTEJ-1</th>
<th>IMPORT</th> 
<th>RADM_OK</th>
<th>RADM_REJET</th>
<th>RADM_KO</th>
<th>RPEC_OK</th>
<th>RPEC_REJET</th>
<th>RPEC_KO</th>
<th>FACTU_OK</th>
<th>FACTU_REJET</th>
<th>FACTU_KO</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($this->suiviprodjours as $value): ?>
  <?php foreach ($value as $key => $val): ?>
<tr>
<td <?php echo $val[$key]["01.DRPLAPOSTEJ-1"].'<br>';  ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

The result :

[image]

Comment: There may be something odd in the way you generate the source array as you have quotes round the first key (`["'01.drplapostej-1'"]`).  This doesn't affect a `foreach()` but just looks odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `foreach()` like below:-

```
<?php foreach($array as $arr){?>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($arr as $value){?>
            <td><?php echo $value;?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

So full code will be:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>01.DRPLAPOSTEJ-1</th>
        <th>IMPORT</th> 
        <th>RADM_OK</th>
        <th>RADM_REJET</th>
        <th>RADM_KO</th>
        <th>RPEC_OK</th>
        <th>RPEC_REJET</th>
        <th>RPEC_KO</th>
        <th>FACTU_OK</th>
        <th>FACTU_REJET</th>
        <th>FACTU_KO</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($array as $arr){?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach($arr as $value){?>
                <td><?php echo $value;?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this snippet for dynamic header and data,

```
echo "<table>";
$keys = array_keys($arr[0]);
//if you want to make upper cases
$keys = array_map("strtoupper", $keys);
echo "<tr><th>";
echo implode("</th><th>", $keys);
echo "</th></tr>";
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo implode("</td><td>", $value);
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

[Demo](https://paiza.io/projects/aQ3Gg_ZsvL2m9aYFmreTYQ).

Comment: @NicoBoulein I updated my answer, with the demo. Please check. A single loop will be enough